# What other ways to get my expo go to load?

Tags: android, css, ios, node.js, tailwind-css

it wasn't loading in the beginning of the project because i had node version 18 installed, someone online suggested to downgrade the node version to 16 in order for it to load and it works perfectly fine.  The problem is node 16 is not compatible with tailwindcss, and so I uprgraded it back node version 18.  It's no loading now.

I've tried uninstalled everything and reinstalled everything back but no hopes